# How can I check checkbox in JavaScript? (not using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my .html

```
<input id="input" type="checkbox">
<button id="button">wait...</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

and .js

```
function isChecked(){
    if(document.getElementById("input").checked){
        document.getElementById("button").fisrtChild.nodeValue= "Checked";      
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button").fisrtChild.nodeValue= "Unchecked";
    }
};

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", isChecked);
```

I want to change the content in button tag when checkbox is clicked but my code doesn't work.

(There is no change when i click)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Without evaluating the code, may as well point out "fisrtChild" is in there twice

Comment: `input` is definitely a bad `id` for an element.

Comment: `firstChild` not a `fisrtChild`.

Comment: You should be introduced to the browser console. It would give you a big helpful hand. Press F12 now.

Comment: Also you can improve function a little: `document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = this.checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in there when referencing `firstChild`. Just tested on jsfiddle.net and it works with the following code:

```
function isChecked(){
    if(document.getElementById("input").checked){
        document.getElementById("button").firstChild.nodeValue= "Checked";      
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button").firstChild.nodeValue= "Unchecked";
    }
};

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", isChecked);
```

Here we are http://jsfiddle.net/q4apn0qz/

Comment: Thank you so much 
I spent about three hours solving this problem... T.T